# debug data method qabstracttablemodel

Tags: c++, qt

I am subclassing QAbstractTableModel to show a list of high scores in a Table View. My data is not displayed. I found that the data method is not called. headerData , rowCount, columnCount are called and seem to work properly. My question is how to debug for this problem, does anyone know where in the qt source code to insert breakpoints to debug for this error?

Comment: Are you emitting `dataChanged(....)`, or `rowsInserted(....)`, etc. to notify the views that the model is different?

Comment: Also double check that you're actually overriding the data function properly (things like function `const`ness are easy to overlook and can cause your attempt to override a virtual function to fail)

Comment: I am not emitting any signal. My data does not change at all. I construct all the model and I pass it to the table view with set model. Should I do some initialization in order to view the data?

Comment: This is the signature of my data function QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

Comment: Have you implemented the following: `index()`, `parent()`, `rowCount()`, `columnCount()`, and `data()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in the way in which I was constructing the model. I was doing

ScoreTableModel pstm(0,pscores);, where pscores is QList < HighScore > *
scoresTableView->setModel(&pstm);

The version that is currently working is:
   m_pScoreTableModel = new ScoreTableModel(0,  pscores);
    scoresTableView->setModel(m_pScoreTableModel);
where m_pScoreTableModel is ScoreTableModel*

Does anyone have any idea why I was having this strange behavior? Could it be because of this QList < HighScore > * which is actually the contents of the table to be displayed?

Comment: It's dead simple. The first approach created the model on the stack. As soon as you exited that scope, the model was destroyed. You own the model, the view does *not* own the model. If you destroy the model, the view won't have anything to show!